Beginner's troubles with binary thresholding for particle tracing in ImageJ
I'm a researcher working on making crystalline microspheres (100-400µm diameter), and have recently begun taking SEM images of my samples. It would be really useful to be able to have a quantitative way to grade my samples based on their roundness from images, and Fiji/ImageJ seemed the natural choice for this.
I've become familiar with the general workflow for particle analysis in Fiji, but I've run into trouble with thresholding. Below is an un-edited SEM image of a particle I'd like to characterize (I use .tif files in Fiji, but converted to .png to post here):

I process the image by setting the scale, converting the image to 8-bit, and move on to threshold & binarize the image, but I can never seem to reduce the "inside" of the particle to solid white. This is the closest I can get, the result of using "subtract background" (200px rolling-ball radius, sliding paraboloid) followed by Fiji's auto-threshold function with the "triangle" preset and converting to binary:

The binary image looks much less uniform than many other thresholding/binarizing examples I see around the Web, and seems to prevent me from getting any usable results from the "Analyze Particles" feature.
I'd greatly appreciate any advice you all could offer on what I'm missing here, or tips in general. Many thanks in advance!
